# Should I do the fp animation separate from the character animation or do them together?

Tags: animation, mesh, rigging

I'm creating a fps game and I dont know how to create the animations. I creating the fp animation which is only with the hands but I need also an animaitons of the character doing the same things such as reaload or shooting should I create one set of animtion for the fp and one for the character of just create one which include the character and the fp hands?
thanks for the answerers :)

Comment: Aren't the First Person's hands & arms the character's arms? Are they not parts of the same model? An animation can be stored as *Action* and it can be applied to different rigs. The rigs must be similar, e.g. the bone layout must be similar and names must be the same.

Comment: Yes they are I didnt know that u can copy from one to other that's nice thank you!, but I am asking about in the game engine do I need to create each one separately or just create only for the character(which include the arms) and just place the camera in a spasific spot?